# Bubble não alterando os valores da lista

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados

Quando executo a primeira **consultaLista()** os dados são mostrados no console, porem, após executar o **bubbleSort()** a consulta não exibe os dados.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <iostream>

#define TAM 10 // Define constante para o tamanho do vetor de dados

/*
 * Nesta questão foi escolhido trabalhar com Lista pois
 */

using namespace std;


struct Aluno {
    int RU;
    string nome;
    string email;
};

struct Lista {
    Aluno dados[TAM];
    int ult;
};

Aluno criaAluno(int RU, string nome, string email) {
    Aluno aluno;
    aluno.nome = nome;
    aluno.email = email;
    aluno.RU = RU;
    return aluno;
}

void iniciarLista(Lista *lista) {
    lista->ult = -1;
}

bool listaCheia(Lista *lista) {
    return lista->ult == TAM - 1;
}

void consultarLista(Lista *lista) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= lista->ult; ++i) {
        cout << "Ru: " << lista->dados[i].RU << endl;
        cout << "Nome: " << lista->dados[i].nome << endl;
        cout << "Email: " << lista->dados[i].email << endl << endl;
    }
}

void insereNoFim(Lista *lista, Aluno aluno) {
    if (listaCheia(lista)) {
        cout << "Lista cheia!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    lista->ult++;
    lista->dados[lista->ult] = aluno;
}

void insereDadosNaLista(Lista *lista) {
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(2524388, "Artur asd", "asdasd@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(1, "Lorem", "sample@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(2, "Ipsum Dassi", "ipsum@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(3, "Artorios", "dolor@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(4, "Marcos", "notenouht@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(5, "Antonio", "samplthis@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(6, "Marcus", "notnotnot@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(7, "Felipe", "heythere@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(8, "Daniele", "bangitdy@gmail.com"));
    insereNoFim(lista, criaAluno(9, "Soulja", "samplethis@gmail.com"));
}

void buubleSort(Lista *lista) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= lista->ult; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= lista->ult; ++j) {
            Aluno atual = lista->dados[j];
            Aluno prox = lista->dados[j + 1];

            if (atual.RU > prox.RU) {
                lista->dados[j] = prox;
                lista->dados[j + 1] = atual;
            }
        }
    }


}

int main() {
    Lista alunos;

    iniciarLista(&alunos);
    insereDadosNaLista(&alunos);
    consultarLista(&alunos); //Quando executado aqui, os valores aparecem
    buubleSort(&alunos);
    consultarLista(&alunos); //Aqui não

    cout << alunos.dados[1].nome << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Em `buubleSort()`, a função escreve fora dos limites do array `Lista *lista->dados` quando `j = 9`.   O problema poderia ser corrigido se você substituísse a linha `for (int j = 0; j <= aux.ult; ++j)` por `for (int j = 0; j < aux.ult; ++j)`. Mas me parece que essa função tem mais problemas do que isso já que você não aplica a ordenação diretamente na variávell `Lista* lista`, mas sim na cópia `Lista aux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu bubbleSort tem alguns problemas:

1. Ele tenta acessar índices inválidos do vetor de dados:

```
    Aluno prox = aux.dados[j + 1]; //Quando j = 9, j+1=10 (índice inválido)
```

Aqui você deveria fazer j variar de 0 até ult-1

```
for (int j = 0; j <= (aux.ult - 1); ++j)
```

2. Você esqueceu de usar o índice `i`.
3. Ele não está ordenando a sua lista original, mas sim uma cópia dela:

```
Lista aux = *lista;
```

Esta linha cria um novo objeto `aux` copiando sua lista original. Portanto, você faz o sort todo na cópia enquanto o objeto original permanece alterado. Para alterar a lista original, você deveria usar a sintaxe de ponteiro usando o objeto `lista` que recebeu como parâmetro.

Comment: Eu tinha copiado e colado aqui a o código anterior, tinha criado o aux para teste. Mas os dois primeiro itens me ajudaram, obrigado!!